# How do I fix this AbstractMethodError when I try to get Pellet working with OWL API?

Tags: owl, protege, pellet

I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.OWLAPIServiceLoaderModule.lambda$loadFactories$1(OWLAPIServiceLoaderModule.java:97)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.OWLAPIServiceLoaderModule.loadFactories(OWLAPIServiceLoaderModule.java:95)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.OWLAPIServiceLoaderModule.configure(OWLAPIServiceLoaderModule.java:52)
at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62)
at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340)
at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.createInjector(OWLManager.java:104)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.getOWLDataFactory(OWLManager.java:63)
at OntController.<init>(OntController.java:86)
at Driver.main(Driver.java:9)
```

whenever I try to use OWLManager, i.e. `df = OWLManager.getOWLDataFactory();` or `manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();`.

I've noticed that this error started appearing ever since I imported Pellet via maven.  This is the dependency tag in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ansell.pellet</groupId>
    <artifactId>pellet-owlapiv3</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there a way to get Pellet and the latest version of OWL API working?  I'm not sure how to resolve this error.

Comment: The name is `pellet-owlapiv3` - what does this mean? yes, it's based on OWL API v3...isn't this obvious? Next, I don't know which version you're using...but google is your friend: https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Reasoners,-OWL-API-Support,-papers-about-the-OWL-API you can find a link there to Pellet for OWL API v4. For OWL API, gain I used google...https://github.com/Galigator/openllet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running Pellet with OWLAPI 5. Pellet has no releases compatible with owlapi 5, you need to use the latest Openllet release.